# Correct term for marinating+degorging/macerating at the same time?

Tags: sugar, fruit, language, marination

Sometimes it makes sense to marinate fruit or vegetables with water-extracting ingredients (sugar,salt,alcohol...) and flavorings (spices or extracts) at the same time, and later use fruit and liquid separated. For example, one might want to have the fruit with lower water content for baking or frying, and the liquid for sauce or batter. And you don't mind both being seasoned.

Is this still correct to describe as a marination in a recipe, or is it more of a degorging (does this always imply the liquid is unwanted?) or maceration? Is there an unambigous term that can be used?

Comment: There is no common term in the French or Italian canons that I'm aware of that covers this. Marination usually implies acid. Maceration usually implies softening or tenderizing. Brining usually implies salt and liquid. Pickling usually implies vinegar or lacto fermentation. I think curing would probably cover it, but it doesn't always involve liquid.
But why do you need such a precise term? Usually cooking terms refer to the process and not the physical and chemical action. Preserved lemons undergo a curing/dry brining process, but we still call them preserved lemons, with little confusion.